# phpmyadmin doesn't start in XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

i have installed XAMPP and at first apache an mysql wasn't starting but when i changed the port number from 80 to 8080 the apache started and i stopped the default mysql running and the it was possible to start mysql from the XAMPP. But the problem is now that when i click the "admin" button along the apache and mysql its suppose to open phpmyadmin but it doesn't.

instead it says not found and

```
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

how can i solve the problem ??

Comment: Check your error log and see exactly what resource is being requested :)

Comment: My initial guess would be you are missing the port number (as you have changed it from port 80) from the URL - maybe it isn't picked up in the admin button.  Try this in your browser - couldn't enter this as an answer due to localhost in the link : http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

Comment: there is nothing in the error log i mean in the box below it just says in both case of apache and mysql that "status change detected:running" and when when i click admin nothing is stated in the box @JonStory

Comment: ishrak, look in the apache log, not in the box below :)

Comment: it worked but how can i configure that when i click admin in the xampp it will by default go to the link : localhost:8080/  @n34_panda

Comment: I am afraid I am not sure if you can - maybe worth googling...It may not even be possible (I thought it defaulted to localhost/xampp and it cannot be amended).  I would recommend simply bookmarking the url above

Comment: Just a correction of wording: phpmyadmin is not something which should be started or be running.
Phpmyadmin is a set of php scripts, which are being run when the pages are being viewed in the browser.